# Default value of line-width in HTML, or how to set box height to N lines

Tags: html, css

What is the default value of line-height in built-in HTML style, i.e. how many `em` does one line height takes?

Alternatively, how to set length (border width) to N lines of text?

Comment: The default value of line-height is around 1.2 but that is not fixed - it will vary from browser to browser - depends on user-agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets the line height to a ‘reasonable’ value relative to the element’s font face. Browser dependent results. CSS2 recommends a computed value between 1.0 and 1.2.

Comment: So to be able to portably and in browser-independed way set length (e.g. border width for "slantalicious" trick from css/edge) to height of N lines I'd have to explicitly set line-height e.g. to 1.2, and set length to N*1.2 ems, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family. Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment as it does not directly offer a solution to the question + is an exact duplicate of what i already commented.